# Your challenge is to make a script that reverses a word then replaces letters

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to make a script *with the shortest byte count*, that reverses a word then replaces each letter with the next letter next in the alphabet.

Examples:

```
input: hi
output: ji

input: hello
output: pmmfi

input: test
output: utfu
```

A few notes:

- Should the letter's value be 27 (`z`+1), assume it is an `a`.
- Symbols, numbers (and any other characters not found in the alphabet) as inputs should error

Comment: What does 'z' map to?

Comment: z will be a, i forgot to put that in it

Comment: make sure it causes an error if you input a symbol or number

Comment: This challenge has multiple problems. What should we do with uppercase/lowercase letters? How about non-ASCII Unicode letters? What is a "word"? What should we do when the input contains spaces? What should we do with 'z' and 'Z' (z->a and Z->A, or z->A and Z->a)?

Comment: Also, it is discouraged to validate inputs as part of the task ("cause an error if a symbol or number is given"), and we usually score a source code in bytes, not characters.

Comment: Nice attempt, but try to explain your question well next time, and instead, post in the sandbox before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 109 bytes

```python
p=input()
print(''.join(chr(ord(c)+1)for c in p[::-1]).replace('{','a').replace('[','A')if p.isalpha()else 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcixCgIxDADQvV/RLQlq8XA7cPA7DodSczRSmtDWQfz46ugbn71H1nqZ065S7TWQnDWpAwHCU6Viyg21PTDRYaFdm09eqrdtXU/LnUJjKzExwgeOEOEvtl/cgGT3FqTHYjkicenszzRnFpe5FHWD@/gC)

This is working also for uppercase letters, since also them are included in the alphabet.

Code explanation:

```python
p=input()
# takes the input from the prompt
              
                                                                              if p.isalpha()
# main check: if the string contains all alphabetic characters

              chr(ord(c)+1)for c in p[::-1]
# reverse the word and returns a list of the next characters in the alphabet (ascii value +1)

      ''.join
# creates a string from the list
             
                                            .replace('{','a').replace('[','A')
# substitutes in the new string the characters '{' (='z' + 1) and '[' (='Z' + 1), to remap 'Z' 'z' to 'A' 'a'

print
# returns the modified word or 0 if a non letter character is present in the input string
```

Answer (score 2):

## Whispers v1, <s>349</s> 343 bytes

```
>> #2
> Input
>> [13]
>> LⁿR
>> Each 20 27
>> Each 4 29 30
> 0
> 65
> 90
> 97
> 122
>> 8…9
>> 10…11
>> [12]
>> Then 14 3
>> Then 3
>> Then 15
>> 7-L
>> ≻L
>> ?L
>> 'L
>> L∈R
>> 2ⁿL
>> LⁱR
>> (1]
>> Each 18 25
>> Each 23 26
>> 1⋅16
>> 1⋅17
>> Each 22 5 28
>> Each 24 6 5
>> Each 19 31
>> Each 4 6 32
>> Each 21 33
>> Output 34
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/9/OTkHZiMtOwTOvoLSEC8iLNjSOBdE@jxr3B4EYronJGQpGBgpG5nCeiYKRpYKxAVAbCJuZAglLEMsSqETB0MgIpNDiUcMySxDD0ADIMjSEmG0ENjskIzVPwdBEwRjOQbAMTUFMc10fEPWoczeYtgeT6j4Qh3V0gB1mBHQhVKRxI1hEwzAW7kZDCwUjU4T7jRWMzMCuedTdaohgIfxkZKRgqmBkgeCbKJgpIAwwBHrYECkAzBSMjRBqDRWMwT7wLy0BBqOCscn//4lJySmpaekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZVVjk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn7@AYFBwSGhYeERkVEA)

In Whispers, the last line is executed first. The other lines are executed when they are referenced in an executing line. Since this program contains many nested operations, I will try to explain it in a bottom-up approach.
For better understanding, I will go through the explanation using the example input `HelloWorld`.

**Input:**

<sup>2</sup> `>> Input`

Takes the first line of input. Example: `HelloWorld`

**Constants:**

<sup>7</sup> `> 0`
<sup>8</sup> `> 65`
<sup>9</sup> `> 90`
<sup>10</sup> `> 97`
<sup>11</sup> `> 122`

Simple integers.

<sup>12</sup> `>> 8…9`

Returns the set {result of *line 8* .. result of *line 9*}, so we get `{65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90}`.

<sup>13</sup> `>> 10…11`

We get `{97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122}`.

<sup>14</sup> `>> [12]`

Converts the result of *line 12* into a list. We get `[65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]`. Since this array occurs several times in this explanation, I will call it `A`.

<sup>3</sup> `>> [13]`

`[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]`. We call this array `B`.

<sup>15</sup> `>> Then 14 3`

```
[A, B]
```

<sup>16</sup> `>> Then 3`

```
[B]
```

<sup>17</sup> `>> Then 15`

```
[[A, B]]
```

**Functions:**

Functions take an argument `L` and/or an argument `R` from a previously executed line.

<sup>4</sup> `>> LⁿR`

Returns the `R`th position of `L`.

<sup>18</sup> `>> 7-L`

Takes the result from *line 7*, subtracts it with `L` and returns it. Since the result of *line 7* is `0` *line 18* simply negates its argument.

<sup>19</sup> `>> ≻L`

Increments `L`.

<sup>20</sup> `>> ?L`

Returns the integer representation of `L`.

<sup>21</sup> `>> 'L`

Returns the string representation of `L`.

<sup>22</sup> `>> L∈R`

Returns true if `L` is in `R`, else false.

<sup>23</sup> `>> 2ⁿL`

Returns the `L`th position of the result of *line 2*. Since *line 2* is our example input `HelloWorld` it will return the `L`th character of this word.

<sup>24</sup> `>> LⁱR`

Returns the index of `R` in `L`.

**Variables:**

<sup>1</sup> `>> #2`

Returns the length of result of *line 2*. In this example it is `10`.

<sup>25</sup> `>> (1]`

Returns the set {1 .. result of *line 1*}, so we get `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`.

The `Each` command iterates over the second argument and applies the function given by the first argument. If two arrays are passed, they are zipped.

<sup>26</sup> `>> Each 18 25`

```
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

<sup>27</sup> `>> Each 23 26`

```
dlroWolleH
```

<sup>5</sup> `>> Each 20 27`

```
[100, 108, 114, 111, 87, 111, 108, 108, 101, 72]
```

<sup>28</sup> `>> 1⋅16`

```
[B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B]
```

<sup>29</sup> `>> 1⋅17`

```
[[A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B], [A, B]]
```

<sup>30</sup> `>> Each 22 5 28`

```
[True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False]
```

<sup>6</sup> `>> Each 4 29 30`

```
[B, B, B, B, A, B, B, B, B, A]
```

<sup>31</sup> `>> Each 24 6 5`

```
[3, 11, 17, 14, 22, 14, 11, 11, 4, 7]
```

<sup>32</sup> `>> Each 19 31`

```
[4, 12, 18, 15, 23, 15, 12, 12, 5, 8]
```

<sup>33</sup> `>> Each 4 6 32`

```
[101, 109, 115, 112, 88, 112, 109, 109, 102, 73]
```

<sup>34</sup> `>> Each 21 33`

```
emspXpmmfI
```

**Output:**

<sup>35</sup> `>> Output 34`

Outputs the result of *line 34*.

But why the strange order? Because [the order is essential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219842/90812). The *lines 1-6* are called several times. So they should better be on a small number line.